# What do you call this type of statement?

Tags: single-word-requests

Assume someone says, "When individual investors enter the market, I know it's time to get out." The speaker is making a serious statement -- yet he is an "individual investor" himself.

What do you call this type of statement?  It sounds like *hypocrisy* or *irony*, but neither term is on target.

Comment: _Self-ownage_ is in vogue among the youth, I believe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps the term you are looking for is ***contradictory*** statement. Note that Cerberus makes a useful comment below.

You might also consider ***paradoxical*** statement.

Comment: Or more specifically *self-contradictory*, because there is not only contradiction but also implicit self-reference.

Comment: To fix the statement: "When _other_ individual investors enter the market..." The error is much like saying you are taller than everyone in the room.

Answer (score 3):

Another possibility, if you don't like the connotations of "contradictory", would be to call it a *self-negating* statement, along the lines of Groucho Marx's "I refuse to join any club that's willing to accept me as a member."

Answer (score 0):

Does the speaker consider himself an individual that is an agent for a company, not an individual-invertor. That is not a individual that is investing, but an individual that invests (over peoples money).

Therefore: Ambiguous, thought provoking ...

Answer (score 0):

Although I think paradoxical (given above) is the best answer, perhaps recursive or self-referential would also apply.